# Create custom Form in Microsoft Dynamic CRM 4.0?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am very new in Microsoft CRM. I need to create one Custom form on entity except the default form provided by CRM. is there any way to create it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create an IFrame that takes up the whole default tab.  The IFrame can point to your custom HTML or ASPX page.  Here is more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150849(v=MSDN.10).aspx

Hope that helps!